# Do `readline`, `readlines`, `writeline` and `writelines` require `file` object `f` to be opened in text mode not binary mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A`file`object `f` has following IO methods, according to Python in a Nutshell:

> f.read(size=-1)
>
> In v2, or in v3 **when f is open in binary mode**, read reads up to size
>   bytes from f’s file and returns them as a bytestring. read reads and
>   returns less than size bytes if the file ends before size bytes are
>   read. When size is less than 0, read reads and returns all bytes up to
>   the end of the file. read returns an empty string when the file’s
>   current position is at the end of the file or when size equals 0. In
>   v3, **when f is open in text mode**, size is a number of characters, not
>   bytes, and read returns a text string.
>
> f.readline(size=-1)
>
> Reads and returns one line from f’s file, up to the end of line (\n),
>   included. When size is greater than or equal to 0, readline reads no
>   more than size bytes. In that case, the returned string might not end
>   with \n. \n might also be absent when readline reads up to the end of
>   the file without finding \n. readline returns an empty string when
>   the file’s current position is at the end of the file or when size
>   equals 0.
>
> f.readlines(size=-1)
>
> Reads and returns a list of all lines in f’s file, each a string
>   ending in \n. If size>0, readlines stops and returns the list after
>   collecting data for a total of about size bytes rather than reading
>   all the way to the end of the file; in that case, the last string in
>   the list might not end in \n.

Do `readline` and `readlines` require `file` object `f` to be opened in text mode not binary mode?

The Same question for `writeline` and `writelines`.

Comment: There is no `writeline`. One should add `\n` explicitly (just like with `writelines`).

Answer (score 1):

No, they also work in binary mode, splitting on `b'\n'`, and returning a list of `bytes` objects.

Tried with Python 3.5.2, got this output:

```
[14:52:44]adamer8:~ ()$ cat Sample.txt
country
code
bold
hello
yellow
country
code
bold
country
[14:52:48]adamer8:~ ()$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('Sample.txt','rb')
>>> content = f.readlines()
>>> print(content)
[b'country\n', b'code\n', b'bold\n', b'hello\n', b'yellow\n', b'country\n', b'code\n', b'bold\n', b'country\n']
>>> type(content[0])
<class 'bytes'>
>>>
```

when opening the file with mode 'r' instead, we get strings:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('Sample.txt','r')
>>> content = f.readlines()
>>> print(content)
['country\n', 'code\n', 'bold\n', 'hello\n', 'yellow\n', 'country\n', 'code\n', 'bold\n', 'country\n']
>>> type(content[0])
<class 'str'>
>>>
```